# Вывод массива из функции С++

Tags: c++

Есть код, который выводит только по одному элементу массива, но если я печатаю все элементы, то на вывод получаю странные числа типа: -876765756889; Как мне вывести весь массив без ошибок?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class TimeConverter {
public:
    int* time_convert(int sec) {
        int hrs = sec / 3600;
        int arr[3];
        int min = (sec % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (sec % 3600) % 60;
        arr[0] = hrs;
        arr[1] = min;
        arr[2] = seconds;
        return arr;
    }

};



int main()
{
    int sec;
    int* new_arr;

    TimeConverter my_time;
    cin >> sec;

    new_arr = my_time.time_convert(sec);
    cout <<new_arr[1]<< " "  << new_arr[2] << endl;

}
```

Comment: Нельзя возвращать указатели на локальные переменные из функции. Сразу после выхода из области определения указатели становятся не валидными.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем вам для этого класс, но раз уж он есть - то воспользуйтесь этим!

```
class TimeConverter
{
    int arr[3];
public:
    int * time_convert(int sec)
    {
        int hrs = sec / 3600;
        int min = (sec % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (sec % 3600) % 60;
        arr[0] = hrs;
        arr[1] = min;
        arr[2] = seconds;
        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы возращаете локальный массив, поэтому у вас там какой-то мусор(произвольные данные).
Тривиальное решение, прокидывать динамический массив и заполнять

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TimeConverter {
public:
    /// прокидываем массив, заполняем
    void time_convert(int sec, int* arr) {
        int hrs = sec / 3600;
        int min = (sec % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (sec % 3600) % 60;
        arr[0] = hrs;
        arr[1] = min;
        arr[2] = seconds;
        return arr;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int sec;
    /// выдялем память динамически
    int* arr = new int[3];

    TimeConverter my_time;
    cin >> sec;

    my_time.time_convert(sec, arr);
    cout << "H: " << arr[0] << " M: "<< arr[1]<< " S: "  << arr[2] << endl;
    // удаляем массив
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: time_convert - уберите return 0; Замените int* arr = new int[3]; на  int new_arr[3]; - не надо делать new/delete